# Which SNMP version My AGENT has implemented

Tags: snmp

I have few basic questions on SNMP Agent implementations, some of these questions may be invalid also, but please let me know

1. Is there any way to find from SNMP Manager that which version of SNMP
   the agent supports?
2. Is that possible that a agent support multiple SNMP versions?
3. If a agent supports multiple SNMP versions, while issuing a get request for an OID, which version of SNMP do I need to set?
4. Is there any possibility in a SNMP Agent that few OIDs are implemented using V1 and few OIDs using v2c and few using SNMPv3, if so, how the manager dynamically finds this to issue a request?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should assume that all agents must be manually registered into a manager with its IP address and credentials. SNMP standard does not have an auto-discovery mechanism.
2. It is possible that an agent supports v1, v2c, and v3 all together.
3. The response message type (v1, v2c, or v3) purely depends on the message type of the request. They must match.
4. That's possible (as the standard does not forbid such), but generally speaking it should be completely avoided. As far as I know no manager can dynamically do what you described.

Usually the SNMP manager only allows you to define an agent by an IP+version pair. So an agent with multiple version support can be treated as multiple agents (each with a single version) at the same IP address. Thus, if an agent supports multiple versions, in manager you should register the highest version. That's enough for the agent management.

Answer (score 0):

Below answers are based on my research and implementation ..........

1. Yes we can get the version of snmp using it's in-built api
2. Yes snmp supports backward compatibility.
3. Yes we can implement several OIDs in v1, v2 and/or v3. Dynamically differentiation is being done by the library(like net-snmp library) which in-turns calls the registered call back function.

Library checks the request message type (for more information, go through the SNMP v1/v2/v3 PDU Format) and decides dynamically which message decoding technique should be used and which callback function should be called.

cheers ..... :)